# Is there a way to force intellij to mvn reimport before I build everytime

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to refer to the versions using ranges in my pom

e.g.
[13.1.0-betatest101,13.1.0-betatest110]

When I upload a new version of jar to the nexus hosted within our company maven seems to pick it up and download it to local repository. But intellij is still referring to old version of the jar. The only way to fix is to mvn reimport but is there a way to force this behavior before every build so I am always working with latest version?

Comment: I usually recommend to prevent using version ranges...Apart from having problems with IDE's...

Comment: You can try to set intellij to automatically download the new sources.